# Creating a Deck of Cards

Tags: java, arrays, object, playing-cards

I'm can't seem to figure out how to create this simple deck of cards.  If somebody could please show an example of what would go into the "your code goes here" section, it would be very helpful.

By entering suitable code in place of the comment in the following main method, create a deck of cards:

```
public class Card 
  { 
    private String mySuit; 
    private int myValue; 

    public Card( String suit, int value ) 
    { 
      mySuit = suit; 
      myValue = value; 
    } 

    public String name() 
    { 
      String[] cardNames =  
        { 
          "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
          "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
          "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" 
        }; 

      return cardNames[ myValue - 2 ] + " of " + mySuit; 
    } 
  } 

  public class MainClass 
  { 
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    { 
      Card[] deck = new Card[ 52 ]; 
      String[] suits = { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"  }; 

      int i; 
      for ( i = 0 ; i < suits.length ; i++ )
      {
        for ( int k = 2 ; k <= 14 ; k++ ) 
        {
          // your code goes here

        }
      }  

      for ( Card card : deck ) 
        System.out.println( card.name() ); 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you've copied and pasted your homework assignment.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: `Deuce`? That's not in any card decks I've ever seen.

Comment: Casino poker dealers are taught to use the terms "deuce" and "trey" rather than "two" and "three".

Comment: I've actually made the majority of it before my winter break, and didn't touch it till now (2 weeks later).  I'm having coders-block and can't think of how to do this for some reason.

Comment: @Quill That's a normal name for "two", for example in Poker.

Comment: You should think about using Enums instead of Strings and String arrays.

Comment: @Quill Bridge players (which I am, when I have time) often refer to the 2 as the "deuce".

Comment: Although it should be pointed out that while "ace", "deuce", and "trey" are common terms for cards, the terms themselves originated with dice.

Comment: @Tom ah, my bad, perhaps I should, uh, [research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuce) before I make such frivolous accusations.

Comment: @HitmarCurse you don't remember how to use constructors, declarations and how to initialize?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have the time to test this, but what's intended is something like:

```
deck[13 * i + k - 2] = new Card(suits[i], k);
```

though personally I would use integers for suits as well--just a waste of time and space to use strings.

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why I couldn't get this.